# Undefined local variable or method `f' on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am making a very simple rails program and hit this error.
>   `undefined local variable or method f` the error is in `form.html.erb` following is the code

```
Extracted source (around line #45):
    44 <div class="field">
    45 <%= f.check_box :public, id: :public, class: "filled-in" %>
    46 <label for="public">Public</label>
    47 </div>
```

> So, could you please give me some ideas?  I am a newbie and very confuse with this error.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole HTML code?

Comment: Paste `form.html.erb` code here

Answer (score -1):

You should post your `form.html.erb` file in your question in order to help us to help you.

Anyways, you probably did a mistake in the way to declare the form in your ERB file.

Be sure to have declared the `f` variable like so:

```
<%= form_for @model_instance do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :public, id: :public, class: "filled-in" %>
    <label for="public">Public</label>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also be sure you did no mistakes in the indentation.

While the above will work, the following wouldn't:

```
<%= form_for @model_instance do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.check_box :public, id: :public, class: "filled-in" %>
<label for="public">Public</label>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This is because the `<%= form_for @model_instance do |f| %>` line opens a Ruby block, in which the `f` variable is available, but not outside of it.

Not indenting the code would exclude it from that block, even do your code be between the `<%= form_for @model_instance do |f| %>` and the `<% end %>`.